# decoding Jackson Tree Model

Tags: java, jackson

```
 DATA1 = {"metrics": {"code1": 0, "code2" : 100}  }
 DATA2 = {"metrics": {"code1": [10,20,30]}}

CODE
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(m);

JsonNode metric_node = rootNode.path("metrics");
Iterator iterator  = metric_node.getFields();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     logger.info("class_name=> {}", iterator.next().getClass().getName());
     logger.info("content=> {}", iterator.next());
}


OUTPUT (for DATA1)
class_name=> java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
content=> code1=0
class_name=> java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
content=> code2=100

Don't know about DATA2
```

I am not able to iterate through the hashmap.I tried iterator.next().getKey() etc. but not working. How do I

Comment: Please share the data `m` that you are trying to read.

Comment: By "through the hashmap" I'm guessing you mean through each map of JSON data returned (like {"code1": 0, "code2" : 100}). Also, what version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: @MikeKobit: yes you are correct. I am using           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.3</version>

Comment: I don't believe that you are using 2.3.3, because they changed the `getFields()` to just `fields()`. I don't believe that is your problem, though. Source: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonUpgradeFrom19To20#Tree_model_method_name_changes_.28JsonNode.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only iterating over the outer keys of the JsonNode you are visiting. And since you are printing out the name of the actual class, that is why you are getting the logged output about the `LinkedHashMap$Entry`. Take a look at the return type of the `metric_node.getFields();`

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator  = metric_node.fields();
```

You are essentially iterating over each node at that level. But since you call `iterator.next()` twice, you are hitting both keys and the loop is terminating. If you tried to run this code on **DATA2**, you would get a `NoSuchElementException` because you are iterating over more items than your iterator actually knows about.

So, you are not actually looking at any of the values associated with those keys. If you change how your loop processes the `JsonNodes` you will see what keys/values are at each field. If you have nested objects that you wanted to go through, you would need to traverse through each JsonNode

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(DATA1);

JsonNode metric_node = rootNode.path("metrics");
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator  = metric_node.fields();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("class_name=> = " + next.getKey());
    System.out.println("content=> = " + next.getValue());
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
class_name=> = code1
content=> = 0

class_name=> = code2
content=> = 100
```

Comment: next.getValue() gives IntNode instead of int. I tried getIntValue() and several others. it just does not get the int. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: For which data set? If you are not seeing the results you want I highly recommend that you take a good look at the Javadoc for whichever class you are trying to use, i.e. [JsonNode](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)